# GitLab cache does not reliably find matching files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My gitlab CI is as follows:

```
stages:
  - test

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  paths:
    - mymark

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ls -l
    - echo "hi" > mymark
    - ls -l
  tags:
    - myrunner
  only:
    - dev
```

The file `mymark` is created by the build scripts:

```
$ ls -l
total 76
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    3 Mar 15 10:48 mymark
```

But GitLab does not see it:

```
Creating cache 122f151d6b0a9d37cfa2172941d642e5c48287fc...
WARNING: mymark: no matching files                 
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

This seems to happen randomly: sometimes the file is found, sometimes not:

```
Creating cache 63d295dad175370aa61d13c4d2f3149e050df5e0...
mymark: found 1 matching files               
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53953122/320399

Answer (score 3):

This is because `cache` can only be used for files inside your project, so even

```
cache:
  paths:
    - /my_root_path
```

will let GitLab CI look for /home/user/yourproject/my_root_path.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you `cd` out of the original directory in any `before_script` or `script` directive.

Make sure you `cd` back to the original directory you were in so the `cache` code can see the paths its looking for.